# gitlab-ci.yml cannot resolve predefined environment variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In my .gitlab-ci.yml i'm trying to deploy on merge request.
My pipeline works, script is executed , everything is ok and running , but i'm not able to read any predefined environment variables. My files looks like :

```
 executeAutomationTests:
  stage: check
  only:
    refs:
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
```

But $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME is not resolved. I need to know source branch for the merge_request in order to pull the code and make a deployment. I have tried other variables like : $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME, $CI_JOB_STAGE , but non of them are resolved.

My GitLab version : GitLab Community Edition 13.4.2

Comment: Your job definition appears correct. I would take a closer look at your job output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in the pipeline job monitor the variable wasn't resolved and that's confused me. It was looking like :
[image]

So, for anyone who is fighting with such things, keep that in mind and also, keep in mind differences in syntax between powershell , bash and so on ..